# R Shiny: Invalidate data periodically in reactive() yet not force DB call first time

Tags: r, shiny

I have a plot resulting from a DB query. I load data to refresh in the plot in the shiny app. To do this, I am using a combination of reactive() and invalidateLater(), but it is forcing a data load even the first time the plot is rendered. Is there any way to make the app use pre-fetched data for the plot, and invalidate/reactive cycle for background processing?

Sample code below (replace mtcars with some function that forces a long DB query):

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(mainPanel(plotOutput('mpg')))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mpg <- renderPlot({
    p <- ggplot(mtcarsReactive(), aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = mpg)) +
      geom_boxplot()
    print(p)
  })

  mtcarsReactive <- reactive({
   invalidateLater(60000)
   mtcars
   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Your code does not show anything about pre-fetched data.

Comment: Let us say I can store away the data frame (mtcars) at initialization time (separate R code) and want to use that on first call to reactive.

Comment: It is hard to provide a reproducible example with a real call to the database. I am showing with generic data set. The above code works. Now, I want the first call to reactive() to return something else, and all subsequent calls to invalidate and return refreshed data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to rely on a global variable. You can define a global variable outside the ui/server functions (for example, `firstRun <- 1`). Then in your reactive

```
mtcarsReactive <- reactive({
    invalidateLater(600)
    if (first == 1) {
        first <<- first + 1
        return(mtcars)
    } else {
        return(diamonds)
    }
})
```

Note the `<<-` assignment, which will assign the value to the global variable, instead of creating a new local variable (if you use normal `<-`).

I tested this under a newer version of Shiny than yours (because mine requires a `session` object in `invalidateLater`), but hopefully it works on your environment.